# finding coefficients of $x^{47}$ in polynomial expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if $f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)\cdots \cdots \cdots (x-49)(x-50).$ then finding coefficients of $x^{47}$ in $f(x)$.

Attempt : $$f(x) = x^{50}-(1+2+3+\cdots +50)x^{49}-(1\cdot 2+1\cdot 3+\cdots \cdots +2\cdot 3)x^{48}-(1\cdot 2\cdot 3+1\cdot 2\cdot 4+\cdots +2\cdot 3\cdot 4+\cdots)x^{47}$$

so coefficients of $\displaystyle x^{49} = \sum^{50}_{i=1}i$

same way coefficients of $\displaystyle x^{48} = \sum^{50}_{1\leq i<j\leq 50}ij =\frac{1}{2}\bigg[ \sum^{50}_{i=1}(i)^2-\sum^{50}_{i=1}i^2\bigg]$

could some help me how to get  coefficients of $\displaystyle x^{47} = \sum^{50}_{i<j<k\leq 50}ijk=$,

thanks in advanced

Comment: It doesn't lead to an easy answer by hand, but $f(x)$ is the falling factorial $(x-1)_{50}$. Consequently its coefficients can be expressed in terms of the Stirling numbers which are well-known and tabulated. (Perhaps one can proceed via the recursion relation for the Stirling numbers.)

Comment: Actually, using an identity in Wikipedia's page on [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), I obtain the relevant coefficient as $$\begin{bmatrix} 51 \\ 48 \end{bmatrix}=\binom{51}{2}\binom{51}{4}=\frac{51\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48}{2\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}=318622500.$$ But how to get that down to a tractable computation...?

Comment: Another way to solve this without using Stirling numbers:$$\begin{align*}
6 \cdot \sum^{50}_{i<j<k\leq 50}ijk &= \left(\sum_{i=1}^{50}i\right)^3 - \sum_{i=1}^{50}i^3-3\sum_{i\neq j}i^2j \\
&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^{50}i\right)^3 - \sum_{i=1}^{50}i^3-3\sum_{i=1}^{50}i^2(1275-i) \\
&= (1275)^3 + 2\sum_{i=1}^{50}i^3-3\sum_{i=1}^{50}i^2(1275) \\
&= (1275)^3 + 2(1275)^2-3825\cdot \frac{50*51*101}{6} \\
&= (1275)^3 + 2(1275)^2-3825\cdot 42925 \\
&= 2075923125 - 164188125\\
&= 1911735000
\end{align*}$$
Thus, the required answer is $1911735000/6 = 318622500$.

Comment: @Ojas how did you replaced $j$ with $1275-i$ in your second line.Thanks

Comment: That $j$ can take all values from $1$ to $50$ except $i$. Thus, just replace it with the sum of all numbers from $1$ to $50 (1275)$ minus $i$.

Comment: @Semiclassical You can move your fine comment to an answer.

Comment: @Ojas You can move your fine comment to an answer.